# Add image to textarea onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add each different image I click on into the textarea, but I can only get the first image to add.

Just to add I am using [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#more-demos). So here is what the html looks like:

```
<div class="item link" id="images_available">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/msluploads/'.$image['name'].'" class="img-responsive img-post"/>
    <div class="after">                                                                     
        <span class="zoom">
            <i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i>
        </span>
    </div></div>
```

The HTML above gets duplicated for every image that is displayed.

Here is what I got so far:

```
$('.link').on('click', function(event){
        var $this = $(this);
        var someimage = document.getElementById('images_available');
        var myimg = someimage.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
        var mysrc = myimg.src;
        if($this.hasClass('clicked')){
            $this.removeAttr('style').removeClass('clicked');                 
        } else {
            $this.addClass('clicked');
            tinyMCE.get('post_imagetxt').setContent(mysrc);
        }
});
```

Comment: Add the code related to owl-carousel

Comment: Does the PHP `'.$image["name"].'` get duplicated also?

Comment: Isn't this line: `someimage.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]` always selecting the first image?

Comment: Irrelevant to the answer as @JonathanLam prompted  $image['name'] will not be rendered cause it should be <?php print $image['name'] ?>

Comment: you should have the onClick event not on the wrapper but on each image, (right now you use '.link' which is the wrapper) then use the event data to figure which one was clicked and change whatever you need to change for that.

Comment: @iamthestreets since you loaded jQuery you could use jQuery's function instead of javascript's

Comment: ^^ Actually the variable `$image["name"]` is concatenated  by single quotes ...   This is already no doubt in the middle of an `echo` @JmRag

Comment: @JmRag I was thinking as Zak was - it's probably part of some PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If

> The HTML above gets duplicated for every image that is displayed.

is completely true, you will have the id `images_available` in your DOM multiple times. Ids have to be unique though. You always get the first one because

```
document.getElementById('images_available');
```

will always get you the first element with this id since it doesn't expect any others in the DOM.

You should be able to fix this by just using `this` instead of `someimage`:

```
var myimg = this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
```