# Add each image to text area on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was able to get my answer for the original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688240/add-image-to-textarea-onclick), but I had to change the way I was doing it and now it is not working. So this is what I changed it too:

```
foreach ($image_data as $key => $row) {
    //print_r($row);
    echo '<div class="item image-link" id="img_link" onClick="myFunction()">
            <img src="'.$row['s3_link'].'" class="img-responsive img-post" />
            <div class="after">                                                                     
                <span class="zoom">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>';    
}
```

This is one of many different ways I have tried to do it:

```
function myFunction() {
            var $this = $('.image-link');
            var myimg = document.getElementsByClassName('img-post')[0];
            var mysrc = '<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img src="'+myimg.src+'" class="img-responsive" alt="image missing" /></a></div>';
            if($this.hasClass('clicked')){
                $this.removeAttr('style').removeClass('clicked');             
            } else{
                $this.addClass('clicked');
                $('.selected-images').append(mysrc);
            }
     }
```

The problem is it will add the class `clicked` to all images and it will only append the first image.

I should also add the only way the function can work is if I take it out of `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Aside from answer below you should be using unique id values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> jQuery class selector will select all the elements having mentioned class irrespective of the context in which it is invoked.

It is never suggested to use inline function to bind events in JS. You should use `.on` to bind events.

Using inline-event binding, you must pass `this` argument as an argument to the function to be called. As jQuery is included, `getElementsByClassName` can easily replaced by `$('.className')` but that will not help in this case as you are suppose to `.find()` the element which is child of the clicked parent.

Also  note that you should not have multiple elements having same value for `id` attribute.

Try this:

```js
function myFunction(elem) {
  var $this = $(elem);
  var myimg = $this.find('img.img-post');
  var mysrc = '<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img src="' + myimg.attr('src') + '" class="img-responsive" alt="image missing" /></a></div>';
  if ($this.hasClass('clicked')) {
    $this.removeAttr('style').removeClass('clicked');
  } else {
    $this.addClass('clicked');
    $('.selected-images').append(mysrc);
  }
}
```

```css
.clicked {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item image-link" onClick="myFunction(this)">
  <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="img-responsive img-post" />
  <div class="after">
    <span class="zoom">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i>
                </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item image-link" onClick="myFunction(this)">
  <img src="http://cordis.europa.eu/docs/news/images/2011-10/20111021-3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-post" />
  <div class="after">
    <span class="zoom">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i>
                </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item image-link" onClick="myFunction(this)">
  <img src="http://rs661.pbsrc.com/albums/uu332/ilovemooks/nature-1.jpg~c200" class="img-responsive img-post" />
  <div class="after">
    <span class="zoom">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i>
                </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using `.on()` :**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var myimg = $this.find('img.img-post');
  var mysrc = '<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img src="' + myimg.attr('src') + '" class="img-responsive" alt="image missing" /></a></div>';
  if ($this.hasClass('clicked')) {
    $this.removeAttr('style').removeClass('clicked');
  } else {
    $this.addClass('clicked');
    $('.selected-images').append(mysrc);
  }
}

$('.image-link').on('click', myFunction);
```

```css
.clicked {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item image-link">
  <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="img-responsive img-post" />
  <div class="after">
    <span class="zoom">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i>
                </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item image-link">
  <img src="http://cordis.europa.eu/docs/news/images/2011-10/20111021-3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-post" />
  <div class="after">
    <span class="zoom">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i>
                </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item image-link">
  <img src="http://rs661.pbsrc.com/albums/uu332/ilovemooks/nature-1.jpg~c200" class="img-responsive img-post" />
  <div class="after">
    <span class="zoom">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i>
                </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked! You saved me hours of work! I should say more hours of work as I have already spent a couple of hours trying to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem: `var $this = $('.image-link');`. It selects all elements with the class of "image-link".

It is also unnecessary as the function is getting passed the item that is clicked upon; it can be referred to by using `this`. All you need to do here is get rid of the variable declaration, and replace "$this" with "$(this)"

Edit:
Also, I'm not positive here, but I'm betting that the reason it doesn't work within `$(document).ready(function() {});` is because you are using the inline "onclick" attribute. If you use event listeners (e.g. `$('.image-link').on(...`), it should be irrelevant.